# undefined reference to method in another class

Tags: c, android-ndk

I have an NDK project where I need to communicate with some C files.
In my project I have all the C files in one place but when I try to call a function from one of the C files in my project - I get the "undefined reference to 'locationEngine'.

My wrapper.c file is trying to call 'locationEngine' function in locationEngine.c file.

I've added #include "locationEngine.h" in my wrapper.c so it should have a reference to it!

The only thing I can think of is maybe the CMakeLists.txt is not defining something?

here's wrapper.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "locationEngine_types.h"
#include "locationEngine.h"


... removed for brevity

{

    // build struct0_T from our POJO LocationStruct that is passed in
    struct0_T input = buildLocationStruct(env, locationStruct);
    // add the default locEngParams
    input.locEngParams = locEngParams;
    // add user params - first time it's an initialized struct with all 0's;
    input.userParams = userParam;
    // pass a reference to them
    locationEngine(&input, &output);

}
```

Here is CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(wrapper SHARED
            wrapper.c)

# Include libraries needed for wrapper lib
target_link_libraries(wrapper
                      android
                      log)
```

Here is wrapper.h

```
#include "../../../../../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h"
#include "locationEngine_types.h"
#include "locationEngine.h"

#ifndef LOCATIONENGINE_WRAPPER_H
#define LOCATIONENGINE_WRAPPER_H

struct0_T extractLocationStruct(JNIEnv *env, jobject locationStruct);

void init();

void destroy();

void start();

void stop();

#endif //LOCATIONENGINE_WRAPPER_H
```

P.S - I'm new to C code.

Comment: C don't have class and don't have method.

Comment: as I wrote - new to C code. thanks though